# Exchange Web Service Search PDF Body

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, exchangewebservices

Tasked with developing a small service that will go through a mailbox folder and check to see if certain documents were actually sent to customers. The goal is to take the manual process of searching in Outlook from the users and automate it.

For example we'll have an invoice, and the user will manually go into that mailbox and type into the "insta search" search bar the invoice number. When they do this, the results will return an email even if the only place the invoice number is located is inside the PDF itself. Example below...

> Emai Object Properties:
>
> Subject: Cust Name 1-1-2017
>
> Body: Attached are invoices for charges on 1-1-2017
>
> Attachment: Cust Name 1-1-2017 (inside the actual PDF is the only location in this email where the actual Invoice Number is located, which is what I'm searching for).

Doing research it looks like this is possible through something called an iFilter that we must have installed on the Exchange Server?

My question is using EWS is there anyway to leverage that functionality of searching the bodies of the PDFs? My current code is below and works if the invoice number is in the subject or body, but we rarely do that anymore and it would be a substantial ask of a process change. Should mention that I'm really just looking to see if a result is returned for the specific invoice number so I don't need the PDFs actually returned by EWS.

```
        //initialize the service
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("email");
        //get everything ready for the search
        List<SearchFilter> searchFilterCollection = new List<SearchFilter>();
        searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "invoiceNumber"));
        searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Body, "invoiceNumber"));
        searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Attachments, "invoiceNumber"));
        SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, searchFilterCollection);
        //item view settings
        ItemView view = new ItemView(50);
        Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox("inboxLocation");
        FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mailbox);
        //find the results
        FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(folderId, searchFilter, view);
        foreach (Item item in results.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what version of Exchange your using on 2010 you had to install the ifilters as an option. On 2013 and up that where installed by default so PDF content should be included in the Exchange Content indexes.

Your code however won't search the content indexes for this you need to use AQS or KQL using the QueryString Parameter in Finditems see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579420(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: So after asking the Exchange team our sever is indeed on 2013 and PDF indexing is turned on. When switching to using an AQS string instead of the search filter like so : "attachment:invoiceNumber" or "body:invoiceNumber" it still doesn't return the results. However the same AQS typed into the outlook search box does return the email. Any other ideas or something I'm doing wrong with the AQS?

Comment: Try it without using a the property qualifier so you just searching for the Search Phrase

Comment: So I tried and still a no go. However I was curious so I went ahead and did these same tests on my own inbox, as well as a coworker (after I was granted permissions). The searches DO work using just the search phrase in both inboxes. It's strange, almost like something is wrong with the original mailbox's indexes. Sometimes using EWS results will return when the phrase matches something in the body content and sometimes it wont' even though through the outlook client I get the results I would expect 100% of the time. Any guidance I could maybe give our Exchange team on settings?